# working with pictures in excel VBA

Tags: image, excel, vba

I have 6 pictures.  I need to make a drop down box with names of all pictures, then when user selects a certain value from drop down box, I need to select that picture, copy and paste it into designated place in my excel file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I ended up doing, maybe not elegant, but got the job done for now:

Sub DropDown60_Change()

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Picture 19").Visible = False
    .Shapes("Picture 20").Visible = False
    .Shapes("Picture 21").Visible = False
    .Shapes("Picture 22").Visible = False
    .Shapes("Chart 4").Visible = False
    Select Case .Shapes("Drop Down 60").ControlFormat.Value
    Case 1
        .Shapes("Picture 19").Visible = True
    Case 2
        .Shapes("Picture 20").Visible = True
    Case 3
        .Shapes("Picture 21").Visible = True
    Case 4
        .Shapes("Picture 22").Visible = True
    Case 5
        .Shapes("Chart 4").Visible = True
    End Select
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: If your drop down is in a cell and named myDropDown you can select picture like this: `ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Range("myDropDown").Value).Select`  Hope this helps get you started.